# How can I get a list of deployed commits from Capistrano 3?

Tags: capistrano3

Immediately following a deploy, I'd like to do some post-processing on the list of commits that were just deployed, but I'm not sure how to get that list in the context of Capistrano's config/deploy.rb.

Comment: commits as in plural? Since when? The last deploy?  Or are you looking for the hash of the current revision?

Comment: The commits between the previously deployed revision and the revision that has just been deployed, inclusive (I want to process these in the `after :restart` block in deploy.rb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there isn't a native version so you would probably need todo something like this (not tested)

```
current_revision = fetch :current_revision                                                                                                                                                                   
previous_revision = fetch :previous_revision

commits =  capture(:git, "log #{previous_revision}..#{current_revision} --format=%H") )
commits.each_line do |line|
   #do something with the line, which will contain all the commit hashes 
end
```

which should give you the log entries between previous and current revisions.

Comment: This is a capistrano task? because it runs on the context of server, and the deploy server is not a git repo.. so this raise an error: `fatal: Not a git repository`